# Character start with query in room persistent android

Tags: android-room

I have tried the following query but it does not give any result.

> SELECT * FROM details WHERE name LIKE :name

I have used AutoCompleteTextview for searching purpose. is there any query to find with a substring?

Comment: make sure you pass name parameter with % sign.
For eg if you want data which contain 'M' your name param should look like "%M%" or change query like `SELECT * FROM details WHERE name LIKE '% :name % '`

Comment: This solution is not working for me. The query is not recognizing the method parameter in this way but @Query("SELECT * FROM network WHERE name LIKE :nameString || '%'") works for name starts with. I want a solution for name contains not start with.

Answer (score 5):

Like MoinKhan suggested, adding the wildcard to the string before sending to Room worked for me.

```
query = "%"+query+"%";
```

Comment: I think you could highlight a few words for better understanding. I will do it.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this issue and found the nicest solution is to use Sql string concatenation `||` in combination with `%` which represents zero, one, or multiple numbers or characters.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM details WHERE name LIKE '%' || :name || '%'")
fun getDetails(name: String): details
```

This will get the details where the name contains the one we are looking for

Similarly the below will find matches that start with the name

```
LIKE :name || '%'
```

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :firstName ")
User findByName(String firstName);
```

**I think u must use different name for "name"**.